# How to solve Endless Building process of spring boot framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I want to work on spring boot fraemwork . For this purpose I have is installed IntelliJ IDEA and compeleted all the dependencies needed for running  **Spring Application** . But when I run the application it go on endless building process. I don't know what the error is. Under given is the process that it's keep on going.

[image]

Comment: look http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/726004-endless-build-loop

Comment: That isn't endless building... That is actually running your application... That is what `bootRun` does... It isn't the build process, it is the gradle process that is running your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The applicataion has started and everything should be fine. Click the icon in bottom left corner and click the run button this will give you the logs from the server. To make it simplier click run -> edit configuration and create new Spring Boot run configuration and then to run the application You can use the run button in top right corner.